# Send XML to Soap Web service php

Tags: php, xml, web-services, soap, wsdl

I am really new to Web Services and xml and I'am Having problems sending xml to a web server

I' am using SoapCliente Php class

```
$client = new SoapClient($wsdlUrl, $soapClientOptions);
```

I'm not having any problem sending strings

```
$param = ["key" => "somekey"];

var_dump($client->somemethod($parms));
```

But, I am having probles sending xml data as is requered on the web service documentation

```
@WebParam(name = "xml") byte[] xml);
```

On the getTypes method:

```
var_dump($client->__getTypes());
```

Is specified in this way:

**base64Binary xml**

So I first stored the xml file as a string variable and then i tried:

```
$xmlstring = "some xml";    
$xmltosend = unpack('C*', $xmlstring);
var_dump($client->somemethod($xmltosend));
```

And:

```
$xmlstring = "some xml";   
$xmltosend = base64_encode($xmlstring);
var_dump($client->somemethod($xmltosend));
```

The Web Service always send a response acording to the data so if the send was correct i will get some succes xml data. In both cases I get this error:

FILES SENT NOT COMPLY WITH THE ESTABLISHED SPECIFICATIONS: EXTENSION, CODIFICATION

The xml format that i am sending is provided as a test example by the web service's documentation so i think the xml is Ok, so I am clueless of what I am missing.

**Edit**

This is exactly how the params are excected on the documentation

```
@WebMethod
@WebResult(name = "RespuestaRecepcionComprobante")
public RespuestaSolicitud validarComprobante(@WebParam(name = "xml") byte[] 
xml);
```

So i just sended the xml string and it worked

```
$param = ["xml" => $xmlstring];
var_dump($client->validarComprobante($param));
```

It's ok to send the data like this? 
The web service read the xml and send me an Ok response 
I also expect an xml response but I dont know how to catch it

Comment: Can you give us an example how your xml request should look like? Often it 's easier using objects and instances of `SoapVar` and `SoapParam` classes. I 'll try to give you an example, when you edit your question with the xml.

Comment: @ Marcel thank you for comment, it give me more perspective it turns out i was not sending the data correctly . I have edit the question because I have a lot of questions, if you could help me I would aprecciate it a lot